# Simulate click event on react element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to simulate a `.click()` `event` on a [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) element but I can't figure out why it is not working (It's not reacting when I'm firing the `event`).

I would like to post a Facebook comment using only JavaScript but I'm stuck at the first step (do a `.click()` on `div[class="UFIInputContainer"]` element).

My code is:

```
document.querySelector('div[class="UFIInputContainer"]').click();
```

And here's the URL where I'm trying to do it: [**https://www.facebook.com/plugins/feedback.php...**](https://www.facebook.com/plugins/feedback.php?api_key=516792821822250&channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2FP5DLcu0KGJB.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df32e78989ee3c64%26domain%3Dproductodelasemana.top%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fproductodelasemana.top%252Ff21b47c88d96f0c%26relation%3Dparent.parent&colorscheme=light&href=https%3A%2F%2Fproductodelasemana.top&locale=en_US&numposts=5&sdk=joey&skin=light&version=v2.8&width=100%25#)

P.S. I'm not experienced with React and I don't know really if this is technically possible. It's possible?

EDIT: I'm trying to do this from `Chrome DevTools Console`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger a button click from a non-button element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367339/trigger-a-button-click-from-a-non-button-element)

Comment: @Tschallacka answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6367609/5997711) seems could work, but unfortunately I'm not getting any result.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `refs` to get the element in the callback function and trigger a click using `click()` function.

```js
class Example extends React.Component{
  simulateClick(e) {
    e.click()
  }
  render(){
    return <div className="UFIInputContainer"
    ref={this.simulateClick} onClick={()=> console.log('clicked')}>
      hello
      </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how you would apply that on this URL: [link](https://www.facebook.com/plugins/feedback.php?api_key=516792821822250&channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2FP5DLcu0KGJB.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df32e78989ee3c64%26domain%3Dproductodelasemana.top%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fproductodelasemana.top%252Ff21b47c88d96f0c%26relation%3Dparent.parent&colorscheme=light&href=https%3A%2F%2Fproductodelasemana.top&locale=en_US&numposts=5&sdk=joey&skin=light&version=v2.8&width=100%25#) ? can't get it working.

Comment: `e.click is not a function`

Comment: it should be e.target.click()

Comment: This did not work for me, however `e.props` contains whatever functions are mapped onto the element. In my instance it was a checkbox with `onChange`, so in simulateClick `e.props.onChange()` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 79):

React tracks the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events for detecting mouse clicks, instead of the `click` event like most everything else. So instead of calling the `click` method directly or dispatching the `click` event, you have to dispatch the down and up events. For good measure I'm also sending the `click` event but I think that's unnecessary for React:

```js
const mouseClickEvents = ['mousedown', 'click', 'mouseup'];
function simulateMouseClick(element){
  mouseClickEvents.forEach(mouseEventType =>
    element.dispatchEvent(
      new MouseEvent(mouseEventType, {
          view: window,
          bubbles: true,
          cancelable: true,
          buttons: 1
      })
    )
  );
}

var element = document.querySelector('div[class="UFIInputContainer"]');
simulateMouseClick(element);
```

This answer was inspired by [Selenium Webdriver code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/atoms/action.js#L286-L288).

Comment: This is smart, Thanks

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore, perhaps we need to send a "change" event?

Comment: This solution worked beautifully for a while but recently broke. Did you end up finding an alternative @information_interchange ?

Comment: If you guys could provide the version of React that started breaking this, that could help me address the issue with the solution.

Comment: Most of react apps listen to 'mousedown' event instead of 'click', so try `mouseClickEvents = ['mousedown']`

Comment: Awesome solution! This will help me a lot.

Comment: Agreed this no longer works

Comment: it does not works in latest firefox version :/

Comment: Works amazing :-) Thank you so much, deserves bounty

Comment: Yes! This is the answer when trying to simulate click in https://web.telegram.org/a/! Thanks!

Answer (score 49):

With react 16.8 I would do it like this :

```
const Example = () => {
  const inputRef = React.useRef(null)
        
  return (
    <div ref={inputRef} onClick={()=> console.log('clicked')}>
      hello
    </div>
  )
}
```

And simply call

```
inputRef.current.click()
```

Comment: @tam, you mean inputRef.current.handleClick() ??

Comment: @Gajen yeah. Looks like I have made a typo.

Comment: This is the right and best solution.. Thank You.. you saved my day :)

Comment: This is the best answer IMO

Comment: When I use this I get cannot read property click of null after it clicks once

Answer (score 8):

A slight adjustment to @carlin.scott's great answer which simulates a `mousedown`, `mouseup` and `click`, just as happens during a real mouse click (otherwise React doesn't detect it).

This answer adds a slight pause between the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events for extra realism, and puts the events in the correct order (`click` fires last). The pause makes it asynchronous, which may be undesirable (hence why I didn't just suggest an edit to @carlin.scott's answer).

```
async function simulateMouseClick(el) {
  let opts = {view: window, bubbles: true, cancelable: true, buttons: 1};
  el.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("mousedown", opts));
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 50));
  el.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("mouseup", opts));
  el.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", opts));
}
```

Usage example:

```
let btn = document.querySelector("div[aria-label=start]");
await simulateMouseClick(btn);
console.log("The button has been clicked.");
```

Note that it may require page focus to work, so executing in console might not work unless you open the Rendering tab of Chrome DevTools and check the box to "emulate page focus while DevTools is open".

Comment: This didn’t seem to work for me, maybe react detects it differently now?

Comment: it does work for me

Comment: Thank you so much, I was having trouble finding this despite knowing the equivalent for reactjs text fields.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't define a class in your component, and instead you only declare:

```js
function App() { ... }
```

In this case you only need to set up the **useRef** hook and use it to point/refer to any html element and then use the reference to trigger regular dom-events.

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

function App() {
  const inputNameRef = useRef()
  const buttonNameRef = useRef()
  
  function handleKeyDown(event) {
    // This function runs when typing within the input text,
    // but will advance as desired only when Enter is pressed
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      // Here's exactly how you reference the button and trigger click() event,
      // using ref "buttonNameRef", even manipulate innerHTML attribute
      // (see the use of "current" property)
      buttonNameRef.current.click()
      buttonNameRef.current.innerHTML = ">>> I was forced to click!!"
    }
  }
  
  function handleButtonClick() {
    console.log('button click event triggered')
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={inputNameRef} type="text" onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}  autoFocus />
      <button ref={buttonNameRef} onClick={handleButtonClick}>
      Click me</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 4):

Kind of a dirty hack, but this one works well for me whereas previous suggestions from this post have failed. You'd have to find the element that has the `onClick` defined on it in the source code (I had to run the website on mobile mode for that). That element would have a `__reactEventHandlerXXXXXXX` prop allowing you to access the react events.

```
let elem = document.querySelector('YOUR SELECTOR');
//Grab mouseEvent by firing "click" which wouldn't work, but will give the event
let event;
likeBtn.onclick = e => {
  event = Object.assign({}, e);
  event.isTrusted = true; //This is key - React will terminate the event if !isTrusted
};
elem.click();
setTimeout(() => {
  for (key in elem) {
    if (key.startsWith("__reactEventHandlers")) {
      elem[key].onClick(event);
    }
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but how did you run it in “mobile” mode?

Comment: For me it was under __reactProps instead of __reactEventHandlers, but even activating the onClick this way didn't seem to work, or at least not completely.

Comment: Okay I figured it out, it seems you have to modify the event with one extra thing, add a property called nativeEvent = {detail:1}, your tactic works great now!

Comment: This code works in the console, but doesn't work when you run it in the actual code.  How do I find the __reactProps or __reactEventHandlers via code?

Comment: Not sure, I've abandoned this code...

Comment: I figured it out now, thanks though!

Answer (score 3):

Inspired from previous solution and using some javascript code injection it is also possibile to first *inject* **React** into the page, and then to fire a click event on that page elements.

```js
let injc=(src,cbk) => { let script = document.createElement('script');script.src = src;document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);script.onload=()=>cbk() }
injc("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js",() => injc("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js",() => {

class ReactInjected extends React.Component{
  simulateClick(e) {
    e.click()
  }
  render(){
    return <div className="UFIInputContainer"
    ref={this.simulateClick} onClick={()=> console.log('click injection')}>
      hello
      </div>
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<ReactInjected/>, document.getElementById('app'))

} ))
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using React useRef Hooks you can trigger a click event on any button like this:

```js
export default const () => {

    // Defining the ref constant variable
    const inputRef = React.useRef(null);

    // example use
    const keyboardEvent = () => {
      inputRef.current.handleClick(); //Trigger click
    }

    // registering the ref
    return (
       <div ref={inputRef} onClick={()=> console.log('clicked')}>
          hello
       </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer was inspired by [carlin.scott code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54316368/14737721).
However, it works only with **focusin** event in my case.

```
const element = document.querySelector('element')
const events = ['mousedown', 'focusin']

events.forEach(eventType =>
    element.dispatchEvent(
        new MouseEvent(eventType, { bubbles: true })
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually we say ***focus an input*** rather than ***click on an input*** (technically speaking). And what you have here (`div[class="UFIInputContainer"]`) is an input, not a button! (image below)

[image]

### Focus an element in React Functional Component

```
function CustomTextInput(props) {
  // textInput must be declared here so the ref can refer to it
  const textInput = useRef(null);
  
  function handleClick() {
    textInput.current.focus();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        ref={textInput} />
      <input
        type="button"
        value="Focus the text input"
        onClick={handleClick}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

To find this example and more, kindly check the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)