# How to force click button in React JSX via scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, jsx

Assuming I have a button, I have searched all of the web, .click() function does not work for me, I really do need to call the button click just after I press the button so it will click itself once more (double-click). Thanks for the help!

```
<button  id='Button1' className="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" onClick={() => {... // the magic code goes here}}
```

Comment: Can I call onClick event recursively?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulate click event on react element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40091000/simulate-click-event-on-react-element)

Comment: The other solution causes more errors than help

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered instead that you could wrap your "onClick" function and call it twice? This seems much cleaner and easier.

For example:

```
<button id='Button1' className="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" onClick={() => doubleClick()}>

function click() {
  // normal code goes here
}

function doubleClick() {
  click();
  click();
}
```

Comment: I need to execute onClick event twice, not the code inside it in order to firstly submit my form and get response from api server and then quickly fire up the second onClick event

Comment: @MAPInc. For what it's worth, what you're describing is definitely an antipattern. You should be calling the function in a promise after your server responds, not forcing a click event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I can't do so since I have some kind of protected route which can't be accessed outside of render (it is actually wrapped so the authorization works so), the double-click is a wonderful solution there

Comment: I do need to refactor my code, I guess I have no solution for this