# Simulate mouse click reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, arrays, material-ui

I have a project of mine where a click should happen (click first one from collapsed list item), but it should happen automatically without user taking mouse on it(cursor) and clicking it.

that list item collapse comes from material ui.

any idea is appreciated.

my code to try :
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-nested-list-forked-2sqtum?file=/src/components/NestedItem/index.js

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import Collapse from "@material-ui/core/Collapse";

const NestedItem = ({ children }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleIsOpen = () => {
    setIsOpen((prev) => !prev);
  };
  const data = ["Someshit inside Collapse", "Someshit inside Collapse 2"];

  return (
    <List>
      <ListItem button onClick={handleIsOpen}>
        <ListItemText primary={children} />
      </ListItem>
      <Collapse in={isOpen}>
        {data.map((el) => (
          <List>
            <ListItem button>
              <ListItemText primary={el} />
            </ListItem>{" "}
          </List>
        ))}
        <List></List>
      </Collapse>
    </List>
  );
};

export default NestedItem;
```

this should be clicked ('Someshit inside Collapse') when user opens the page and just once, it could print console.log('text Someshit inside Collapse is clicked'):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID to the element you want to click, then you can do something like

```
document.getElementById("elementYouWantToClick").click();
```

Comment: cannot add ID to it if list items come from api

Comment: Do you want the first item to be clicked? If so, you can use the index of the ListItem

Comment: yes first item to be clicked, if there is an item click first one, thats it

Comment: Can you add ID or classes to the parent element?

Comment: i have added more to the code to understand better, that 'data' could be from api

Comment: So you're creating multiple lists instead of list items?

Comment: (upvoted) First thing, I would recommend having everything in list items instead of separated lists if possible. If not, just add an ID to the parent of the lists and do this:

const listElements = document.getElementById("ParentID").querySelectorAll("List");
Then you can iterate through the lists :)

Answer (score 0):

This answer could be what you are looking for:
[Simulate click event on react element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40091000/simulate-click-event-on-react-element)

tldr: You can't just fire `.click()` on the element, you have to simulate `mousedown` and `mouseup` events.

Comment: i just one first item to be clicked if there is any

Comment: You can select the first button from your list by using `yourListElement.firstChild`

Comment: possible working code ?

Comment: You will need to uniquely identify your list, with an id for example, and then you can use 
`document.getElementById('your-list-id-here').firstChild­` to get the first button of the list, then you can dispatch the virtual click events on that element to "click" it.